# Call azure cli ps from azure devops

Tags: devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-cli

I want to execute a powershell script containing the azure cli to create blueprints in azure as a task in the azure devops. I have the ps script in Github and want to give the location of the script in the script location of the Azure CLI task. Can you please let me know how to achieve it  ?

Comment: Any specific reason for not using the Azure CLI or Azure Powershell tasks directly from the Pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the Azure CLI task is used to run a **shell** or **batch** script containing Azure CLI commands. If what you have is a PS script, go with the [Azure Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops).

The Azure CLI/Powershell tasks have a [Script Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops#arguments) argument, but that only accepts a fully-qualified path, or a valid path relative to the default working directory.

Although you could use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Invoking) to download the file to the agent and execute it then, it would not be suggested as you'll have the overhead of incorporating error/exception handling within the task and the pipeline. There is a [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) available for executing scripts that you can leverage.

Hope this helps!